# How to loop through nested objects of a list in svelte

Tags: javascript, loops, svelte, sveltekit

I have a mega menu design with the following data structure

```js
const megaMenuLink = [
   {
     name: 'E-services',
     link: '/e-services',
     hasSubmenu: true,
     subMenuItems: [
            {
                name: "Access E-services",
                link: "/access",
           },

             {
                name: "Register",
                link: "/register"
           }
       ]
    },

        {
        name: "Other services",
        link: "/services",
        hasSubmenu: false,
    }
]
```

I have accessed the name property with {#each} block

```html
{#each megaMenuLink as link}
    <li>{link.name}</li>
{/each}
```

How do I loop through the inner subMenuItems based on condition of 'hasSubmenu' is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either add an `#if` block with another `#each` block inside

```html
<ul>
    {#each megaMenuLink as link}
    <li>{link.name}</li>
        {#if link.hasSubmenu}
        <ul>
            {#each link.subMenuItems as link}
            <li>{link.name}</li>
            {/each}
        </ul>
        {/if}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

or make use of `<svelte:self>` ([docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-self) / [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-self)) when creating a component

```html
<LinkList items={megaMenuLink} />
```

```html
<script>
    export let items
</script>

<ul>
    {#each items as link}
    <li>{link.name}</li>
      {#if link.hasSubmenu}
      <svelte:self items={link.subMenuItems} />
      {/if}
    {/each}
</ul>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/081f5db342a3474e9a97edb4b9fcf61d?version=3.52.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
let name ;
  let link ;
  this.megaMenuLink.forEach((obj)=> {
    if(obj.hasSubmenu === true && obj.subMenuItems){
       name = obj.subMenuItems.map(e=>e.name)
       link = obj.subMenuItems.map(e=>e.link);
    }
  } );
  console.log(name, "and",  link);
   
}
```

// these code works for javascript